# An app in Android phone which can act like "netstat" command in Windows

Tags: android

In Windows with `netstat` command we can find which exe file is connecting to which IP address.
I am looking for such an app for Android phone.

Comment: Not sure which app will cover your needs, but maybe my list of [Network Diagnosis](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis) apps can help?